# Union of two matching sets being a matching

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with parts $A$ and $B$. Let $U\subseteq A$ and $V\subseteq B$ and assume that there exists matching in $G$ that covers all vertices in $U$ and another matching that covers all vertices in $V$. Show that there is a matching that covers all vertices in $U \cup V$. (Hint: consider the union of these two matchings - how does it look like?)

Here is my attempt:

Let $M_1$ be the matching that covers all vertices in $U$ and similarly let $M_2$ be the matching for $V$. Let $M=M_1 \cup M_2$. We need to show that it is possible for $M$ to be a matching that covers the union of $U$ and $V$. Now $M$ would clearly cover all vertices in $U$ and $V$ (should I explain this more) but it might not be a matching because it might have edges that have vertices in common. If $M$ has no edges that contains vertices in common, then we are done so $M$ would be a matching of what we need to show which is described in the question. Assume that this is not the case. Note that for all edges say $uv$ contained $G$, vertex $u \in A$ and vertex $v \in B$, otherwise it wouldn't be a bipartite graph. Let us consider three arbitrary vertices in $G$, say $u\in U$ and $v,p \in V$. Let $uv, up \in M$. Having these two edges would mean that $M$ is not a matching because there is a vertex in common which is $u$. We should note that these two edges cannot be both in $M_1$ or both in $M_2$ otherwise $M_1$ and $M_2$ would not be matching sets. So lets say without loss of generality that $uv \in M_1$ and $up \in M_2$. We can delete edge $uv$ because vertex $v$ will already be covered in $M$ because vertex $v$ will be in $M_2$ - otherwise $M_2$ would not cover all vertices in $V$ since $v \in V$. Since our vertices were arbitrary, after the necessary deletions, $M$ will be a matching that covers all vertices in $U \cup V$.

Please tell me anything at all wrong with it or where it needs more justification. I might have jumped a bit in the last part.
I would want to see how this is best answered.

Comment: The first problem is minor - in sentence 3 you want to say ".. for $M$ to *contain* a matching that covers.." as $M$ may not be a matching. The next problem is that when you "consider three arbitrary vertices in $G$", you assume they're in $U\cup V$. So there are more cases to consider. The big problem: you can't make a "local" decision about removing edge $uv$. Hint: think harder about the structure of $M$: aside from some isolated edges which are in $M_1\cap M_2$, you get a graph in which each vertex has either degree $1$ or degree $2$. What must the components of such a graph look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution which makes use of the hint.  Think of $M=M_1\cup M_2$ (where $M_1$ is the matching that covers $U$, and $M_2$ is the matching that covers $V$) as a *directed* graph; edges in $M_1$ are directed from $A$ towards $B$ ("red"), and edges in $M_2$ are directed the other way ("blue").  Every vertex in $M$ has degree $1$ or $2$, so the components of $M$ are either simple paths or cycles.  Furthermore, the degree-$2$ vertices have one incoming edge and one outgoing edge, so the paths and cycles are directed paths and directed cycles whose edges alternate red and blue.  Note that since vertices in $U\cup V$ have an outgoing edge, a component of $M$ which is a path cannot end in either $U$ or $V$.

We now select edges from $M$ to obtain a matching.  For each path, select alternating edges starting with the first.  If the path has an odd number of edges (hence covers an even number of points) this is a matching between the $A$ points on the path and the $B$ points.  If there's an extra edge, we don't cover the last vertex - but that vertex is neither in $U$ nor $V$ so that's OK.  For each cycle, select alternating edges starting anywhere you like (i.e. take either the red edges or the blue edges).  In either case, you get a matching which covers all the vertices in the cycle.  The resulting matching covers all the vertices in $M$ except for some path endpoints, which were not in $U$ or $V$, hence the matching covers $U\cup V$.$\ \square$

We remark that in the special case that we started with a matching $M_1$ from $U$ into $B$, and a matching $M_2$ from $V$ into $A$, this argument shows that $M$ contains exactly $2^k$ matchings covering $U\cup V$, where $k$ is the number of cycles in $M$.

Comment: can you elaborate more on why M has deg 1 or 2 please

Comment: Also in the first part of the second paragraph, you say '' For each path, select alternating edges starting with the first'', what do you mean by 'starting with the first'???

Comment: I also don't understand where you said in the first paragraph, last part ''a component of M  which is a path cannot end in either U  or V''. how can you be so sure of this?

Comment: A vertex in $A$ has an outgoing edge iff $M_1$ assigns it to something in $B$. We assumed $M_1$ covered $U$, so everybody in $U$ has an outgoing edge.  So if a path reaches a vertex in $U$, it doesn't end -- it continues on via that outgoing edge.  Same thing for $V$.  So the endpoints of paths are in $A\setminus U$ or in $B\setminus V$.  (However, I think they can *start* anywhere.)

Comment: OK now I understand that. But when you said at the start, Let M be a directed graph, do you mean that this graph has all vertices of G because if it doesn't then how can you refer back to parts A and B because M only has vertices of U and V - not all vertices of A and B.

Comment: $M$ is just the union of $M_1$ and $M_2$.  That may or may not cover all the vertices of $G$.  Since $M_1$ covers $U$, the graph $M$ will have an edge out of every vertex in $U$, and maybe out of some other ones in $A$ as well.  Same for $M_2$.

Comment: OK, also what do you mean by 'starting with the first' on the first part of paragraph 2? Im not understanding...

Comment: The paths are directed, so they have a first edge.  Say the first edge goes from $A$ to $B$; it corresponds to an edge in $M_1$ (red).  The next edge in the path comes back from the endpoint of the first edge back to some point in $A$ (blue).  The next edge is red again ($A$ to $B$) and so on.  So if the path starts with a red edge, you'll take all the red edges in the path.

Comment: I really dont understand. Would you be able tp give an example please

Comment: Take A={a,b,c,d,e}, B={1,2,3,4,5}, U={a,b,c,d}, V={1,2,3,4}, M1={a1,b5,c3,d4}, M2={1c,2d,3a,4e}.  Components of M are the cycle a->1->c->3->a, the path 2->d->4->e, and the path b->5.  Take alternating edges from each of these to get a matching: {a1,c3,2d,4e,b5}.

Answer (score 1):

Since the following algorithm finishes and it produces a matching we are done.

Start with $M=M_1$ and let $V'$ be the set of vertices in $V $ not covered by $M$.

Select $v'$ in $V'$, consider the edge in $M_2$ of the form $av$. If $a$ is part of an edge $av''$ in $M$ remove that edge from $M$  and add $av'$ to $M$. Remove $v'$ from $V'$ and add $v''$. If $a$ is not part of an edge $av''$ just add $av'$ to $M$ and delete $v'$ from $V'$.

The reason this algorithm yields a matching covering $U$ and $V$ is that after every step $M$ is a matching that covers $M$. moreover, once $v'$ is deleted from $V$ it is never added again, because $M_2$ is a matching and only one edge of $M_2$ contains $v_1'$. Therefore we obtain a matching covering $U$ and $V$ in a finite amount of steps (at most $|V|$ steps).

Comment: Not sure I understand this :/ Why is $v'$ never deleted again?

Comment: @darijgrinberg no idea, I wrote this a year ago. Let me check it, although it may be wrong.